# How can I change the number of coroutines in the middle of the process?

Tags: multithreading, async-await, python-asyncio, semaphore, python-3.8

I want to make async processing in python3.8,

How can I change the number of coroutines in the middle of the process?

Is it possible to change Semaphore by changing the number of limits along the way?

```
async def exec(id1,id2):
    print(f'start: {id1}  end: {id2}')
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    func = functools.partial(run_insert,id1,id2)
    await loop.run_in_executor(None, func)

async def parallel_call(s2elist,limit):
    sem = asyncio.Semaphore(limit)

    async def call(start,end):
        async with sem:
            return await exec(start,end)

    return await asyncio.gather(*[call(s,e) for s,e in s2elist])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    s2elist = [[1000,2000],
            [2000,3000],
            [3000,4000],
            [4000,5000],
            [5000,6000],
            [6000,7000],
            [7000,8000],
            [8000,9000],
            [9000,10000]
            ]

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(parallel_call(s2elist,10))
```

Comment: Your indentation appears to be off. Can you please fix the formatting in your question?

Comment: It's definitely possible to add coroutines while the program is running; see [`asyncio.create_task()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task). In your case it appears you don't need a semaphore in the first place; it's normally used to **limit** the number of coroutines running in parallel, and your number of coroutines doesn't exceed the specified limit to begin with.